# Angular 2 - Cannot read property '...' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http

Very new to Angular. I checked similar questions but they either dive into specifics or I just don't understand the solutions.

**The actual error:**
"Cannot read property 'idPlanet' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PlanetComponent.html:11)"

**The issue:**
planetDetail.idPlanet is undefined most probably?

**Suspect:**
getPlanetDetail()

planet.component.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  ID: {{ planetDetail.idPlanet }}
</div>
```

planet.component.ts:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

import { Planet }               from './planet';
import { PlanetService }        from './planet.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'planets',
  templateUrl: './planet.component.html'
})
export class PlanetComponent implements OnInit {

    private planets: Planet[];
    private planetDetail: Planet;
    constructor(
        private planetService: PlanetService
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getPlanetDetail();
      this.getPlanets();
    }

    public getPlanets() {
      this.planetService.getPlanets()
          .subscribe(
              (planets) => this.planets = planets
          );
    }

    public getPlanetDetail() {
      this.planetService.getPlanetDetail()
          .subscribe(
              (planets) => this.planetDetail = planets
          );
    }

}
```

planet.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Planet } from './planet';

@Injectable()
export class PlanetService {

    private planetsUrl = 'http://localhost/index.php/api/planet/';  // URL to web api

    // Injecting the http client into the service
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    public getPlanets(): Observable<Planet[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.planetsUrl + 'planets/id_sol/1')
            .map(this.parseData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public getPlanetDetail(): Observable<Planet> {
      return this.http.get(this.planetsUrl + 'planet/id_planet/1')
          .map(this.parseData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private parseData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();

        if (body instanceof Array) {
            return body || [];
        } else {
            return body.post || {};
        }
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss tbh, I tried to build my getPlanetDetail() method from getPlanets() which works fine. Should I use a promise?

I'm having a hard time figuring out where exactly I can put console.log() to debug. I'm using angular-starter kit from Github.

Thanks for your time.

edit 1: the api outputs {"idPlanet":"1","name":"Earth"}

Comment: If you're sure `planetDetail` is populated at some point (asynchronously), try `ID: {{ planetDetail?.idPlanet }}`

Comment: Check this one: `(planets) => this.planetDetail = planets`. Most probably `planets` is undefined. So console inside the `parseData` method to see what is the response of your http call.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what else to put there nothing corresponds.

Comment: Can you share with us the content of [http://localhost/index.php/api/planet/planet/id_planet/1](http://localhost/index.php/api/planet/planet/id_planet/1)?

Comment: @m.spyratos the output is {"idPlanet":"1","name":"Earth"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your response is `{"idPlanet":"1","name":"Earth"}`, try the following:

```
public getPlanetDetail(): Observable<Planet> {
    return this.http.get(this.planetsUrl + 'planet/id_planet/1')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the request is asynchronous sometime the value will not be fetched from the server when the page loads, therefore, the planetDetail is undefined. in order to avoid this you can use add '?' between  planetDetail and idPlanet. that prints only if it has the value

`ID: {{ planetDetail?.idPlanet }}`

If you want to print the result or error 

`public getPlanetDetail() {
      this.planetService.getPlanetDetail()
          .subscribe(
              (planets) => {
                   console.log(planets);
                   this.planetDetail = planets
                 },
              error => {console.log(error);}
          );
}`

Answer (score 1):

my friend to debug if your 'planetDetail' is populated, just add 'console.log (planetDetail)' in the 'subscribe' method. Follow the example below.

```
public getPlanetDetail() {
  this.planetService.getPlanetDetail()
      .subscribe(
          (planets) => this.planetDetail = planets
      );
}

public getPlanetDetail() {
  this.planetService.getPlanetDetail()
      .subscribe(
          (planets) => this.planetDetail = planets, (err) => (err), () => console.log(this.palnetDetail)
      );
}
```

More about subscribe()

```js
subscribe(function(response) {
  console.log("Success Response" + response)
},
  function(error) {
  console.log("Error happened" + error)
},
  function() {
  console.log("the subscription is completed")
});
```

Comment: yeah it is empty

Comment: It happened to me :)